# What happens on update?

Tags: svn, version-control

What happens in this case:

I have this version of code: (VERSION 223)

```
//Return 2
public void a(){
    return 2;
}
```

But a team-mate made two some changes and had commited it twice:

**First**, just erasing the comment: (VERSION 224)

```
public void a(){ 
    return 2;
}
```

And a **second** (VERSION 225)

```
//Now it returns a SUM
public void a(int a , int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

When I run the update command I just overrides using the last version of CODE (225) or it will make two updates the first to VERSION 224 and another from 224 to 225?

Comment: it' interesting to know - but why do you need to know ? I would assume that there is some optimization , if the changes are bigger than the file itself - it will send the full file and merge it , if change set is small - will send the change set and merge it to local file

Comment: @Mzf that's just for curiosity and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.diskspace.deltas) show that SVN is saving only delta.

I would assume that there is some optimization , if the changes are bigger than the file itself - it will send the full file and merge it , if change set is small - will send the change set and merge it to local file.
But didn't find this kind of optimization in this book

Answer (score 0):

When you run `svn update` against your working copy, it sends the current revision number of your WC to the server. The server then calculates a diff between that revision and the latest revision in the repository (AKA `HEAD`), and sends that difference over the wire for your client to apply to your WC.